# Euclidean algorithm - runtime in specific case

Tags: runtime-analysis, diophantine-equation

I'm going to solving many times this specific equations:

$$2^{x+y} \cdot c - a^{y} \cdot z = 1$$

in which $$a$$ can be equal to: $$-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7.$$ And $$x+y$$ will be equal to $$128.$$ It has to be done with euclidean algorithm, but how many step it requires in average in this specific case?

I know that euclidean algorithm requires at most $$5\log_{10}b$$ steps ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency)), where b is the smaller number, but in this case we don't know which number will be smaller, $$2^{x+y}$$ or $$a^{y}.$$ That's why I have a problem with this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem amounts to solving $2^{128} c - a^y z = 1$.  I assume you are given $a,y$ and must find $c,z$ that satisfy the equation.

I suggest you first solve
$$a^y z \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{128}}.$$
This has as solution
$$z \equiv (a^{-1})^y \pmod{2^{128}},$$
so you can find a solution for $z$ by computing the inverse of $a$ modulo $2^{128}$ (using one invocation of the Euclidean algorithm; or by a Hensel lifting method if you prefer), and raising it to the $y$th power using a [fast exponentiation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  Then, compute $c = (1 + a^y z)/2^{128}$.

Comment: Which method is faster? One invocation of the Euclidean algorithm or Hensel lifting method (I don't know this method)?

I also don't understand how to solve equation like this:

$$z \equiv (a^{-1})^y \pmod{2^{128}}$$

How to use one invocation of the Euclidean algorithm to find $z$?

Comment: Ok, probably I understand how to solve this:

$$z \equiv (a^{-1})^y \pmod{2^{128}}$$

For example if we have:

$$3^{19} \cdot z \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{10}}$$

First we can solve:

$$3 \cdot r \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{10}}$$

$$r=683$$

And then:

$$z = 683^{19} \pmod{2^{10}} = 83$$